# scanr1 in Scala?

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming

In Scala, is there a `scanr1`, similar to Haskell's `scanr1` which takes no zero-element and produces the intermediate results that would otherwise be created by an in-order `reduce` operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such function in core Scala. Some of useful functions adopting by Scalaz or other community libraries. For example [Mada](https://github.com/okomok/mada) does have [scanRight1](https://github.com/okomok/mada/blob/8f3a4cc734ff47de67bf07db36e00b62cd35ee13/src/main/scala/sequence/list/List.scala#L329)

Comment: Ah okay. I will stick to good old '(1 :: 2 :: Nil).scanRight(1)(_*_)'